# Why is part of my model black when rendering?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I have used a simple mesh and to corner I sculpt to give some rough shape. I added the boolean modifier to the name and applied all the modifiers. Added the texture as material. Remove doubles & Normals. Looks good in object mode. When I press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> the name looks black.

[image]

**Object Mode**

[image]

**Rendered Mode**

[image]

Comment: Rendered in blender engine or cycles engine?

Comment: @Elmazz its cycles engine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here is a simple way:

[image]

select the area that has black letters by pressing <kbd>B</kbd> and press <kbd>U</kbd> to unwrap and select **Projection from view**

Sorry for the previous answer. Did not test it through enough.

Comment: Thats Perfect know...

Answer (score 0):

Your texture lacks a texture coordinate node. One solution is to select the object in edit mode, press U>Project from view, and then go into the material settings and where it says vector, choose "UV".

[image]

Comment: its not working with the above answer

Comment: whoops xd i'm so unaware today...